# Value ownership in Rust functions

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrowing

I have the following function:

```
fn hmac_sha1<'a>(_message: &'a str, _key: &'a str) -> &'a [u8] {
    let key: &[u8] = _key.as_bytes();
    let message: &[u8] = _message.as_bytes();

    let mut mac: Hmac<Sha1> = Hmac::new(Sha1::new(), key);
    mac.input(message);

    let mac_result: MacResult = mac.result();

    mac_result.code()
}
```

In essence, I want to encode my message using SHA1, and return a pointer to the resulting byte array. When compiling this code, I get the following error.

```
  --> src/main.rs:81:5
   |
81 |     mac_result.code()
   |     ----------^^^^^^^
   |     |
   |     returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
   |     `mac_result` is borrowed here
```

Now, I understand what is wrong here, I just don't know how to fix it. The `mac_result` variable's lifetime expires once the function is finished, and a pointer to its internal result will of course not live any longer.

Is there a way extend the lifetime of the `mac_result` variable so that I can return the byte array it contains, without converting it to a `Vec<u8>`? That's a workable solution, but I'd rather not convert the array if at all possible.

Comment: You can return the *mac_result* to the caller. If you want a prettier interface for that, you could make a wrapper for mac_result, that [derefs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html) to the hash code.

Comment: You can pass byte array's reference as parameter then you can fill it with `hmac::raw_result`  or just return the `MacResult`, only way to increase it's life time is to create it's clone

Comment: Thanks. It makes sense that I wouldn't be able to access a variable outside its scope, but I'm not steady on lifetimes yet, so I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something obvious.

Comment: Another thing is that you do not want or need `_message` and `_key` to have the same lifetime. You can remove any lifetime annotation and it will just work (other than for returning a reference to a local variable, of course).